# How can I emulate websites on different devices in Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation, websites, web-development, web-design

I am working on the front-end of a website and need to see how my code behaves in different systems/browsers. Firefox and Chromium do have development tools that allow the display to be set to different sizes, but they are unable to fully emulate Apple's upscaling mechanism and the sites will still look slightly different. Also they don't take into account different browsers.

Is there any tool or software I can use with Ubuntu to check what my site will look like on different devices/browsers?

Comment: Have you tried using an "User Agent Switcher" extension that allows for Spoofing and Mimicking browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are services like:

1. [Browserstack](https://www.browserstack.com/mobile-browser-emulator)
2. [Mobiletest](http://mobiletest.me)
3. [Responsimulator](http://www.responsimulator.com/)
4. [Appetize](https://appetize.io/) - Probably the best, But painfully slow for me.

The better way still is to actually test the site on a physical device. I've found out that all these ways are slow.

Answer (score 1):

**[responsivepx](http://responsivepx.com/)**

> Enter the url to your site, local or online, and use the controls to adjust the width and height of your viewport to find exact breakpoint widths in pixels. Then use that information in your media queries to create a responsive design.

[responsivepx GitHub](https://github.com/remy/responsivepx)

For best results with responsivepx you need to think outside the box. For some reason I can't get Google and Twitter to show me anything but a blank white screen in responsivepx, even though Bing and complicated news websites render in it just fine.